# Python strftime with timezone offset

Tags: python, datetime, timezone-offset, strftime

is it possible to format datetime object with strftime with timezone offset?

I do have unix timestamp let say `1658123953` converted to python timezone aware datetime object

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 18, 7, 59, 13, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Bratislava' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

and I would like to apply `strftime('%H:%M:%S')` on datetime object to get formatted string with timezone offset added.

I need it in this format

```
'09:59:13' # with timezone offset added
```

but I was only able to get this

```
'07:59:13 +02:00' # not correct format for my case
```

Comment: You are aware that 9:59:13 does *not* correspond to the UTC time? Why do you want to add the timezone offset?

Comment: Because customer expects datetime to be converted to his timezone in format he requested. Therefore I have to add timezone to UTC timestamp and format it in requested format.

Comment: But your result already *is* in the correct (local) timezone. Try for example, `datetime.fromtimestamp(1658123953, tz=ZoneInfo('America/New_York'))` and you'll find the time is 1:59:13. Or try `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1658123953)` and it's 5:59:13. Your time is *not* in UTC; it has the two hours added to UTC already. *That* is what the +02:00 is saying.

Answer (score 1):

Your UNIX Timestamp is

> 1658123953

in UTC this is

> Mon Jul 18 2022 05:59:13

So this is

> 07:59:13 +02:00

the Right Timezone Aware Value

You can Check the Unix Timestamp https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

The Timezone Offset is already added in youre String the "+02:00" is just a reference to the Timeoffset

Comment: This actually is already an answer. Even if it just shows the OP is thinking the wrong way about this.